Reaching performance of unsafe_any_cast using only standard library features
I am using std::any to store a value of any type. std::any is a type-safe container and one of its features is that attempting to reach for the wrong type throws std::bad_any_cast exception. In some cases I can be sure that the stored type is the one I am trying to get, but I still have to go through std::any_cast which checks the stored type info and possibly throws an exception.
Since I can't avoid using std::any_cast I would like to somehow inform the compiler that an alternative to successfully getting the value is not possible, and I would be ok with it causing undefined behavior.
I tried using the following code:
#include <any>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
T __attribute__((noinline)) unsafe_any_cast(const std::any& o) noexcept {
    try {
        return std::any_cast<T>(o);
    }
    catch (...) {
        __builtin_unreachable();
    }
}

int main() {
    std::any obj = 3, obj2 = 5.4;
    std::cout << unsafe_any_cast<int>(obj) << " " << unsafe_any_cast<double>(obj2);
}

I tested it on g++12.3 and clang 18, but assembly for checking an exception still gets generated. This is obviously non-standard due to __builtin_unreachable(), but I could probably replace it with syntactically correct code that causes undefined behavior, such as dereferencing NULL.
I am aware of unsafe_any_cast from boost, but I don't want to use boost.

FYI since C++23 there is std::unreachable.

Since any cast seems to require you can construct the target type from the argument type why not bypass std::any_cast altogether and just return T{o}; (or do I miss something here?)

Why not simply call std::any_cast without any wrapper ? If you are sure that an exception will not be thrown, you will not "pay" for it anyway (AFAIK in C++ exceptions only cost when they are actually thrown - isn't it?).

@wohlstad I believe the intent it to avoid generating instructions that check if the type T is valid.

@FrançoisAndrieux I see. Then I misunderstood this sentence in the question: "but assembly for checking an exception still gets generated".

@PepijnKramer I can't seem to find references on that. Are you sure it refers to std::any?

@LMauricius No, Iam not sure more like thinking out loud after reading the specs on std::any (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)

@wohlstad Unfortunately, checking for type_info still happens, even if exceptions never get caught or cause undefined/unreachable behavior. I haven't tested it without catch blocks, but since I want to have code that never propagates exceptions I'm afraid try blocks are unavoidable. The reason why I worded it that way is because with optimizations on, the code for actually throwing an exception isn't generated, and instead the type_info checks and catch block body essentially fuse.

If you don't want to use boost, you can always learn from its implementation : https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/boost/any/basic_any.hpp :)

@PepijnKramer Ah, I get it where you're getting this from. It refers to the type T being copy-constructible from another object of the same type, not from std::any.
As for taking from boost, I could actually roll-out my own implementation somewhat easily, but since std::any has SO optimization and other functionalities, I'd rather wrap it up with another object than reimplement everything in my codebase. Currently, performance isn't that important, but really nice-to-have.

The any_cast overload that takes a pointer to any is guaranteed to not throw an exception. You can use that if you don't like exceptions.
template<class T>
T __attribute__((noinline)) unsafe_any_cast(const std::any& o) noexcept {
    const T* p = std::any_cast<T>(&o);
    //                            ^ note the address-of operator
    [[assume(p)]];
    return *p;
}

The generated assembly depends on the standard library implementation. For libstdc++, it seems that an indirect call in any_cast prevents the compiler from completely eliminating the type check. I don't think much can be done about that.

On g++12 it doesn't seem to indirectly call any_cast with -O3 and -fwhole-program. While the assume() attribute seems more helpful than non-standard call to __builtin_unreachable(), it doesn't seem to affect anything.

I mean there's a (rarely executed) call rax in the generated assembly, which I wished to avoid. But otherwise I think the assembly is close to optimal.

Oh, and g++ 12 doesn't support [[assume(p)]]. The support was added in gcc 13. You need to replace that assumption with if (!p) __builtin_unreachable();.

Yes, I figured that. I'm mostly testing on g++12 as that's what I have locally, but even on 14 this code doesn't seem to optimize away anything. Note that I used std::any with both int and `double> because having only a single overload used makes the compiler figure out that the cast never fails (on g++14), but for a completely different reason and that optimization gets thrown out of window as soon as we are dealing with multiple types.
